# Divide nodes into cycles

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Can anyone tell how to divide nodes of a graph into cycles so that each node of the graph occurs in exactly one cycle.
I have tried dfs but my solution is giving very large complexity.

constraints of the problem is n<=50.

Also in the question each node is connected to atmost four other nodes.

Comment: This is an algorithmic question. Please remove the C++ tag.

Comment: One quick solution could be, you build cycles with arbitrary nodes. Then consider this cycles as some dummy large vertex for the next phase. Build a DAG by using this dummy large vertices.

Comment: Didn't understand your question. Can you please give some examples of given input and required output?